# Determining counts based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has columns named "surname" and "Date" (DateTime). The table is for vacation requests. How can I construct a SQL statement to see how many people will be missing for each day?. The point is that the query will not show me that actually 8 people will be missing at 2 of september. For example, given the following data:

```
surname Date       Duration
------- ---------- ---------
Bertram 2011-09-01     3
Coulois 2011-09-01     5
LeBlanc 2011-09-01     6
Fosters 2011-09-01     3
Blanche 2011-09-01     2
Bertram 2011-09-02     6
Gillian 2011-09-02     4
Pikklar 2011-09-02     7
Thierry 2011-09-03     6
Selanne 2011-09-03     6
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE #VRs(surname NVARCHAR(32), [Date] DATETIME);

INSERT #VRs   SELECT 'Bertram','2011-09-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Coulois','2011-09-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'LeBlanc','2011-09-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Fosters','2011-09-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Blanche','2011-09-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Bertram','2011-09-02'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Gillian','2011-09-02'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Pikklar','2011-09-02'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Thierry','2011-09-03'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Selanne','2011-09-03';
```

I want the following results:

```
Date  Count
----- -----
1 Sep     5
2 Sep     3     
3 Sep     2
```

Any ideas how to approach it?

Comment: I have reopened after the edit.  I can't do anything about the downvotes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(DAYOFMONTH(`date`), ' ', LEFT(MONTHNAME(`date`), 3)) AS Date, 
       COUNT(surname) AS Count FROM `#VRs` GROUP BY Date
```

Here, `CONCAT` is used to combine the day and the first three letters of the month name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply group vacation requests by date, and return row counts for every date, if I am not missing anything:

```
SELECT
  [Date],
  COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM #VRs
```